# Why does decryption not return the expected value?

Tags: c#, encryption, rijndael, cryptostream

When using c# rijndael to decrypt a string that was previously encrypted and saved in sql server ce, I get nothing back from decryption. I can tell from debugging and checking the database that the decrypted string appears to be saved as expected with different sets of nonsense for different input strings so I assume that the problem is in the decryption code. I also confirmed that cipherText input parameter got the correct number of bytes after being retrieved from the db and re-made into a byte array. I used the example found at:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael%28v=vs.110%29.aspx to do this, with some modifications.

```
static string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments. 
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

        // Declare the string used to hold 
        // the decrypted text. 
        string plainText = null;

        // Create an Rijndael object 
        // with the specified key and IV. 
        using (Rijndael rijAlg = Rijndael.Create())
        {
            rijAlg.Key = Key;
            rijAlg.IV = IV;
            rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);
            var plainBytes = new byte[cipherText.Length];
            int plainByteCount;

            // Create the streams used for decryption. 
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {

                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {

                    plainByteCount = csDecrypt.Read(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);

                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode))
                    {
                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream 
                        // and place them in a string.
                        plainText = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();

                    }

                }
            }
        plainText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);

        }

        return plainText;

    }
```

At

```
 plainText = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
```

plainText gets the value of "" where I would expect it to be the decrypted word.

Finally, at

```
   plainText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
```

plainText becomes:  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"

I have tried various padding options, both at the encryption and decryption stages, and can see that doing so has an effect but it doesn't solve the problem. Without setting padding 0 bytes get encrypted in the first place, where it should be 16  bytes. I also tried different ways of calling flush and flushfinalblock. I am storing the key/iv in plain text files (I am aware that may not be best practice for security,  my goal for now is only to learn more about this topic).

Please help me find what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Btw, you might want to change `if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");` to `if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");`. It'll save headaches later on.

Comment: Did you use the same Key, IV, and encryption algorithm when creating the original byte array?

Comment: What @MingSlogar said, you have to use the same IV and Key from invocation of encrypt to decrypt.  Without knowing what you've done with those, it's really hard to tell what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the similar problem in VB.NET and discovered that the variables to be used in both encryption and decryption process should be the same. Giving the encryption and decryption functions their own local variables would definitely cause the decryption function return a wrong value. Try making the key and the iv a global variable instead of a local variable.

Comment: The IV should not be a global constant. It should be a new random value for each message stored alongside the ciphertext (typically as a prefix).